# Displaying image in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

I am trying to display an image on my JSP page using image tags. May I know what is the tag format i should use? I have stored my image under "image" folder in my project.

Answer (score 4):

check out

```
<html>
<body>

<img src="angry.gif" alt="Angry face" width="32" height="32" />

</body>
</html>
```

from
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_image_test

you probably need
src="/yourcontextroot/resources/images/yourpic.gif"

Comment: you probably need src="<c:url value="/image/yourpic.gif"/>". Hard-coding the context root is a really bad idea.